# Querying arrays in JSON fields

Tags: oracle, query

The DB is `Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.16.0.0.0`.

Suppose we have a table `CASE_ISSUES` with a JSON field `ISSUES_JSON`:

| CASE_ID | ISSUES_JSON |
| --- | --- |
| 105 | [{"issue": "#10"}, {"issue": "#11"}, {"issue": "#12"}] |
| 110 | [{"issue": "#20"}, {"issue": "#21"}, {"issue": "#22"}] |

Is there a way to query this table to get a result like this?

| CASE_ID | ISSUE |
| --- | --- |
| 105 | #10 |
| 105 | #11 |
| 105 | #12 |
| 110 | #20 |
| 110 | #21 |
| 110 | #22 |

The real problem is more complex than what is outlined here, but if a query is possible, then we can proceed with using a JSON field as opposed to adding a lot of association tables. The directive from higher up is to add as few new columns as possible, and ideally to add no new tables.

Comment: Yes querying that is possible but it will be ugly and slow. There's a reason to properly normalize your database tables